# Forcing current on capacitor tied to ground

Tags: capacitor, ground, transient, continuity

I have a device with a capacitor tied to ground.  If a negative current of 1 mA is being forced out of that pin, I am trying to better understand capacitor operation in this area.  My questions are as follows:

1. Is the subsequent voltage measurement for continuity measurement going to measure the voltage across the capacitor?
2. My assumption is that device pin has an internal ESD diode.  Would current higher than 1 mA or the current’s slew rate cause the ESD diode to be potentially damaged and exhibit a short to ground?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Best option to clarify your problem is to add a schematic by using ge built-in schematic tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1  . The result of checking a capacitor for continuity could vary depending on the value of the capacitor. A very small value capacitor will generally show no continuity, (open circuit).
A large value capacitor may show a brief continuity (short circuit) as the capacitor charges, then will show no continuity after a short time, (open).

If a large capacitor were already charged (previously tested) a later continuity test may show an immediate open circuit. If the capacitor were discharged then retested the result should be as above.

After a continuity test on a large value capacitor a volt meter could be connected to show a residual voltage across the capacitor pins.

2  .  If there were an internal ESD component it would cause a short at some high voltage level, (for example during a fast electro-static discharge event).  Most ESD components are capable of discharging a fairly large current for a very brief pulse time, (on the order of amperes not milli-amperes).  If a test voltage were to be raised slowly to a high value it may damage an ESD component if a large current were allowed to flow for more than a brief amount of time. (But before that would happen it is more likely that any other connected components would be severely damaged).